# Temporary adjustment of delay time

Tags: anylogic

I have the following problem which I am unable to solve:

I have a situation where a security point (added as delay) holds every half an hour a 15 min break. After the break, the security guards increase their speed till the queue is shorter than 10pp.

I wanted to model this as follows: a state chart with *delay.set_capacity(0)* after 30 minutes and *delay.set_capacity(1)* again after the 15 min break. For the increased speed after the break, I added an additional state with condition: *queue.size()>10* and now I want to set the action such that the delay function changes the delay time from exponential (1/10) to exponential (1/5) as long as *queue.size()>10*.

Anyone experience with which function in the action box to use? Or would you suggest a different function?

Comment: just use an actual function (from the Agent library) that returns a double. Code it as needed and call that in the delay property for the actual delay duration... hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using, or at least want to use a statechart I would suggest the following design, where you have composite states inside the working state to indicate if the security agent is working fast or normal and a message transition to let it move from one state to the next.

[image]

It is advised to use a message transition and trigger it as needed instead of a conditional state which gets chected for every change inside the agent since this can be a computational expensive exercise.

I assume you already implemented the correct capacity settings for the different on enter actions for working and breaking

[image]

Now you simply need to send the message every time an agent enters the queue and every time it exits the delay block, and of course, see the delay time based on the state of the statechart.
Aee screenshot below.

[image]